# Logging when limit Exceeds

Tags: linux, security, debian, logging, audit

Is there a log file that logs information when the values set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are exceeded?

If the values are too tight in the above file the clients using the website hosted on the server sees errors such as `[FATAL] failed to allocate memory` . But I wont be intimidated about it. So is there a log?

If not is there a way to make it log when the values are exceeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

limits.conf is a too blunt an instrument for what you are trying to do.

cgroups will set limits and provide accounting for you, but the documentation is a little obtuse! https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a log file that logs information when the values set in /etc/security/limits.conf are exceeded?

Nope.

All those values go at last to process resource limits (`man setrlimit`) and when they met there's no universal mechanism to issue an warning to be logged.

Answer (score -1):

if your issue is about memory allocation failed you could also use this script to monitor percentage of free memory left

```
#!/bin/bash
# you can adjust 0.20 meaning 20% to percentage of memory free you want 
output=$(free | grep "Swap" | awk '{if (($4/$2) < 0.20) print "memory low"}')
if [[ "$output" != "" ]]; then
    echo "..." | mail -s "Memory low on <host>" <monitoring email>
fi
```

save it to script file (ex. memmon.sh) and add to crontab it will send email and write log file when detect free memory low as conditioned)

```
# Ex. monitor every 3 min.
*/3 * * * * /home/user/memmon.sh >> /home/user/memmon.log
```